# RHEL 7 multi-user.target disables Wi-Fi

Tags: linux, networking, rhel

Every time I set my system target to multi-user.target, I lose connection to 
Wi-Fi and thus can't control my machine via ssh after a reboot,
and when I go to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`,
I don't find a script for my network card either.

Any reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your WiFi is configured by NetworkManager and you haven't designated the WiFi settings as "usable by any user on the system"? In that case, the WiFi settings are stored as an user-specific configuration item with the desktop configuration settings (in GConf, probably) and are only available to NetworkManager when you've logged in.

By marking the WiFi settings as usable by everyone, the settings should be stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` directory instead, and from there NetworkManager can get them even when you aren't logged in.